# Install error of package plyr

Tags: r

> package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in
>   install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘plyr’

How can I solve this problem ?  I have tried to delete the existing plyr file in C:\ drive but it doesn't work . I also using devtools , it doesn't work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `remove.packages`  like below:

```
library(utils)    
remove.packages("plyr")
```

and then try to install "plyr" using `install.packages("plyr")`. See if it works
You may want to check [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/remove.packages.html) as well.

Comment: It shows this:
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘plyr’

Comment: @SORIFHOSSAINSHUJON  do a `unloadNamespace(plyr)` and/or close the R session and try it again. see if this works

Comment: `unloadNamespace(plyr)` gave `Error in unloadNamespace(plyr) : object 'plyr' not found` but restarting the session worked, thanks!